# Disable pipeline for static files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I recently added OWIN to my existing ASP.NET MVC 5 project.
I'm using it to log the request and response data that comes to my server.

Everything is set up properly, and the logging works great, except for one issue that I'm not entirely thrilled about:  **it logs any static file requests.**

## **How can I avoid logging .js/images/css/etc. requests using the OWIN pipeline?**

One of my custom logs:

```
Request 
Method: GET 
Path: http://localhost:12345/content/stylesheets/site.css.map 
Headers:  ...
Body:  ...
```

I find when I load one of my web pages, I could see 8 log entries get generated from all of the static file loads.  I only care about the main request.

Now, I could go in and *whitelist* or *blacklist* request paths, but I thought before I do that, there had to be an easier way.

**I want to avoid doing this:**

```
_urlsToNotLog = new[]{
    "content/stylesheets/site.css.map",
    "Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
    .
    .
    };

if(_urlsToNotLog.Contains(environment["owin.RequestPath"]))
{
   //log request
}
else
{
    //Don't log
}
```

My code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use<LoggingMiddleware>();
    }
}

public class LoggingMiddleware
{
    public LoggingMiddleware(AppFunc next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> environment)
    {
        LogRequest(environment);
        await _next(environment);
        LogResponse(environment);
    }
```